# Backshift Notation for a Seasonal ARIMA model with constant

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality

When fitting and forecasting using a seasonal ARIMA model with a total differencing of 1 (non-seasonal + seasonal), a constant term is necessary to capture the trend of the original data prior to differencing. In the case of the 'austourists' dataset from the fpp2 package in R, I utilized the auto.arima() function to obtain the model information.

The output of the auto.arima() function for the 'austourists' dataset is as follows:

```
ARIMA(1,0,0)(2,1,0)[4] with drift 
Box Cox transformation: lambda= 0 

Coefficients:
         ar1     sar1     sar2   drift
      0.4330  -0.7100  -0.2369  0.0129
s.e.  0.1183   0.1256   0.1342  0.0018

sigma^2 = 0.004151:  log likelihood = 85.65
AIC=-161.3   AICc=-160.27   BIC=-150.51
```

How should I construct the backshift notation for a 'seasonal ARIMA model with constant' based on this information, given that there is no mean parameter available to calculate the constant from? Should we include the drift parameter in the backshift notation itself?

Thank you!